# issues in jquery of adding and removing values with math.round()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on functionality of `custom plan` in my site.
there are tasks to be added or removed customarily with increase  or decrease values of active tasks..

There are four values in active task : 1 2 3 4

1 will multiply total value by 1

2 will multiply total value by 1.5

3 will multiply total value by 1.4

4 will multiply total value by 1.3

this values can be incremented and decremented..

when active task's value is 1 and I add the plans it works correctly (because removing all plans the total value become 0)
same for other active tasks.

**Problem Statemnet :**

But when active is 1 and I add first two plans and then increment active tasks by 2 and then add third plan it works correctly...but by removing all these 3 plans at the end it gives me -1 value...I think it it because the value could not be rounded correctly..

I also tried the math.ceil() and math.floor() fucntions but with no success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Here is my code :**

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 (function($j) {
  var otherincome = $j(".totalamountremaining");
     $j('.addno').on('click',function(){
         var $jqty=$j(this).closest('span').find('.qty');
         var currentVal = parseInt($jqty.val());
         if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < 4) {
             $jqty.val(currentVal + 1);
             if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 1){
              var firstinc = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0)*1.5);
              $j('.totalamountremaining').val(firstinc);
              $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(firstinc);
             }
             if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 2){
              var secondinc = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0)*1.4);
              $j('.totalamountremaining').val(secondinc);
              $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(secondinc);
             }
             if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 3){
              var thirdinc = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0)*1.3);
              $j('.totalamountremaining').val(thirdinc);
              $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(thirdinc);
             }             
         }         
     });
     $j('.minus').on('click',function(){
         var $jqty=$j(this).closest('span').find('.qty');
         var currentVal = parseInt($jqty.val());
         if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
             $jqty.val(currentVal - 1);
             if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 2){
              $j('.totalamountremaining').val(function(i, val) { return Math.round(val/1.5) });
              $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(function(i, val) { return Math.round(val/1.5) });
             }
             if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 3){
              $j('.totalamountremaining').val(function(i, val) { return Math.round(val/1.4) });
              $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(function(i, val) { return Math.round(val/1.4) });
             }
             if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 4){
              $j('.totalamountremaining').val(function(i, val) { return Math.round(val/1.3) });
              $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(function(i, val) { return Math.round(val/1.3) });
             } 
         }
         
     });
      var primaryincome = $j("#addnumber");
  
  $j(".calculate").click(function () {
   var $jqty=$j('.addno').closest('span').find('.qty');
         var currentVal = parseInt($jqty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 1){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(primaryincome.val()||0) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 2){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome.val()||0) * 1.5)) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 3){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome.val()||0) * 1.5) * 1.4) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 4){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome.val()||0) * 1.5) * 1.4)*1.3) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            $j('.plan.shopifytask .add').hide();
      $j('.plan.shopifytask .remove').show();
      $j('.plan.shopifytask').removeClass('yetadd');
  })
  $j(".shopifytask-remove").click(function () {
   var $jqty=$j('.minus').closest('span').find('.qty');
         var currentVal = parseInt($jqty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 1){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - parseInt(primaryincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 2){
       var totalincome = Math.round((parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome.val()||0) * 1.5)));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 3){
       var totalincome = Math.round((parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome.val()||0) * 1.5)*1.4)));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 4){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.round(Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome.val()||0) * 1.5)*1.4)*1.3));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      $j('.plan.shopifytask .add').show();
      $j('.plan.shopifytask .remove').hide();
      $j('.plan.shopifytask').addClass('yetadd');
  })
    var primaryincome4 = $j("#addnumber4");
  $j(".calculate4").click(function () {
      var $jqty=$j('.addno').closest('span').find('.qty');
         var currentVal = parseInt($jqty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 1){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(primaryincome4.val()||0) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 2){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome4.val()||0) * 1.5)) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 3){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome4.val()||0) * 1.5) * 1.4) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 4){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome4.val()||0) * 1.5) * 1.4)*1.3) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      $j('.plan.designtask .add').hide();
      $j('.plan.designtask .remove').show();
      $j('.plan.designtask').removeClass('yetadd');
  })
  $j(".designtask-remove").click(function () {
      var $jqty=$j('.minus').closest('span').find('.qty');
         var currentVal = parseInt($jqty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 1){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - parseInt(primaryincome4.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 2){
       var totalincome = Math.round((parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome4.val()||0) * 1.5)));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 3){
       var totalincome = Math.round((parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome4.val()||0) * 1.5)*1.4)));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 4){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.round(Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome4.val()||0) * 1.5)*1.4)*1.3));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      $j('.plan.designtask .add').show();
      $j('.plan.designtask .remove').hide();
      $j('.plan.designtask').addClass('yetadd');
  })
var primaryincome5 = $j("#addnumber5");
  $j(".calculate5").click(function () {
      var $jqty=$j('.addno').closest('span').find('.qty');
         var currentVal = parseInt($jqty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 1){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(primaryincome5.val()||0) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 2){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome5.val()||0) * 1.5)) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 3){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome5.val()||0) * 1.5) * 1.4) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 4){
       var totalincome = Math.round((Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome5.val()||0) * 1.5) * 1.4)*1.3) + parseInt(otherincome.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      $j('.plan.wptask .add').hide();
      $j('.plan.wptask .remove').show();
      $j('.plan.wptask').removeClass('yetadd');
  })
  $j(".wptask-remove").click(function () {
      var $jqty=$j('.minus').closest('span').find('.qty');
         var currentVal = parseInt($jqty.val());
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 1){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - parseInt(primaryincome5.val()||0));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 2){
       var totalincome = Math.round((parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome5.val()||0) * 1.5)));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 3){
       var totalincome = Math.round((parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome5.val()||0) * 1.5)*1.4)));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal == 4){
       var totalincome = Math.round(parseInt(otherincome.val()||0) - Math.round(Math.round(Math.ceil(parseInt(primaryincome5.val()||0) * 1.5)*1.4)*1.3));
             $j('.totalamountremaining').val(totalincome);
             $j('.totalamountremaining1').text(totalincome);
            }
      $j('.plan.wptask .add').show();
      $j('.plan.wptask .remove').hide();
      $j('.plan.wptask').addClass('yetadd');
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.plan.yetadd .remove {
   display: none;
  }
.plan-total{
margin-top:50px;
}
.plan-total-price{
margin-left:20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
          
          <div class="plan">
       <span class="plan-text">Active Tasks
        
       <span class="plan-qty addminus">
        <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o minus target1" id="minus2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <input id="qty2" value="1" class="qty" disabled="" type="text">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o addno target" id="add2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </span> 
      </div>
            <div class="plan yetadd designtask">
       <span class="plan-text">Task1
        
       <span class="plan-qty qtywidth">
        <button class="remove designtask-remove"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Remove</button>
        <button class="add calculate4">
           <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <span>Add</span>
          </button>
        <span class="dolorsign">$</span>
        <input value="149" id="addnumber4" class="primaryincome" disabled="" type="text">
        <span class="super">/month</span>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="plan yetadd wptask">
       <span class="plan-text">Task2
        
       <span class="plan-qty qtywidth">
        <button class="remove wptask-remove"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Remove</button>
        <button class="add calculate5">
           <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <span>Add</span>
          </button>
        <span class="dolorsign">$</span>
        <input value="39" id="addnumber5" class="primaryincome priceleft" disabled="" type="text">
        <span class="super">/month</span>
       </span>
      </div>
      <div class="plan yetadd shopifytask">
       <span class="plan-text">Task3
        
       </span>
       <span class="plan-qty qtywidth">
        <button class="remove shopifytask-remove"><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Remove</button> 
        <button class="add calculate">
           <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <span>Add</span>
          </button>       
        <span class="dolorsign">$</span>
        <input value="79" id="addnumber" class="primaryincome priceleft" disabled="" type="text">
        <span class="super">/month</span>          
       </span>
      </div>
            <div class="plan-total">
      <span class="plan-total-text">PLAN TOTAL:</span>
      <span class="plan-total-price">       
       <span class="totaldolar">$</span>
       <input class="totalamountremaining primaryincome priceleft2 price-bold-total" value="0" disabled="" id="txt" type="hidden">
       <span class="totalamountremaining1 primaryincome priceleft2 price-bold-total">0</span>
       <span class="super-total">/month</span>
      </span>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one quick tip. **Separate data from DOM.**

Recalculate money from 0 whenever you click minus or plus buttons.
For example, if you have two active tasks and added Task1 and Task2, you will get 283$.

If you remove one active task, do not start from 283$, just recalculate from 0.
Error of floating point acculumulated as you keep calculating from previous value.